# ansible postgresql module to create role and add database

Tags: postgresql, ansible, centos7, ansible-2.x

I am currently running the following commands

```
 # su - postgres
 $ psql
 postgres=# create role user_name with login encrypted password 'password';
 postgres=# create database database_name owner user_name template template0 encoding 'UTF8' lc_collate 'en_US.UTF-8' lc_ctype 'en_US.UTF-8';
```

I wanted to make use of the [postgresql module in ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/list_of_database_modules.html#postgresql) do so.

So far, I have tried this

```
- name: create the "{{ ovirt_engine_dwh_db_name }}" db from the command line
  command: |
    psql -c "create role {{ ovirt_engine_dwh_db_user }} with login encrypted password '{{ ovirt_engine_dwh_db_password }}';"
    psql -c "create database {{ ovirt_engine_dwh_db_name }} owner {{ ovirt_engine_dwh_db_user }} template template0 encoding 'UTF8' lc_collate 'en_US.UTF-8' lc_ctype 'en_US.UTF-8';"
  become_user: postgres
```

But the error which comes if I try this is that the jinja2 templating does not substitute the variables which I have defined in `defaults/main.yml`

Comment: Are you asking how you would convert the command in your question to postgresql ansible modules or why your current task is failing?  If it's the latter can you include the error output?

Comment: @kfreezy I was curious of how can I convert the command to postgresql ansible module. Would love to check out how I can do it using them. Right now I got it working by creating sql templates and then running them separately on the host machine. The errror was due to the fact that, the task was inside a non-default directory structure and hence could not read from the `defaults/main.yml`

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to split your task into two separate tasks using [postgresql_user](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/postgresql_user_module.html) and [postgresql_db](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/postgresql_db_module.html).

```
- name: Create the "{{ ovirt_engine_dwh_db_user }}" user
  postgresql_user:
    name: "{{ ovirt_engine_dwh_db_user }}"
    password: "{{ ovirt_engine_dwh_db_password }}"
    encrypted: True
  become_user: postgres

- name: create the "{{ ovirt_engine_dwh_db_name }}" db
  postgresql_db:
    name: "{{ ovirt_engine_dwh_db_name }}"
    owner: "{{ ovirt_engine_dwh_db_user }}"
    template: template0
    encoding: UTF8
    lc_collate: 'en_US.UTF-8'
    lc_ctype: 'en_US.UTF-8'
  become_user: postgres
```

Note that the `ovirt_engine_dwh_db_password` can either be plain text or md5 encrypted.  I was able to create an encrypted password on Ubuntu 16.04 using the commands below.

```
export USER=bar                                                        
export PASS=verysecretpassword
echo "md5`echo -n "${PASS}${USER}" | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'`"
```